# ARDUINO pin is constantly changing from HIGH to LOW?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, gpio

I used this code to check the state of Arduino pin 8.
To see if the pin is High or Low but my output continuously changes from high to low.

I am not connecting anything to pin 8 while running this code.

```
const int Pin = 8; 
int Reading=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000);
  pinMode(Pin, INPUT); 
}

void loop() {
  Reading = digitalRead(Pin); 
  if(Reading == HIGH)
  {
    Serial.println("HIGH");
    delay(2000);
  }

  if(Reading == LOW)
  {
    Serial.println("LOW");
    delay(2000);
  }

}
```

But my Output Comes like this:
OUTPUT:

```
HIGH
HIGH
LOW
LOW
HIGH
HIGH
LOW
LOW
HIGH
HIGH
LOW
LOW
HIGH
HIGH
LOW
LOW
```

Don't know what to do ??

Comment: You might want to learn what the pinouts are rather than test them and be bewildered by what you find. The pinout diagram says it's clk0, so it's probably outputting a clock signal.

Comment: Yup. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI

Comment: @Will He's not initializing SPI, so it shouldn't be real cause. He is, however, stating "there is nothing connected" and the code shows: `pinMode(Pin, INPUT);`, so it might be more like floating input issue.

Comment: If nothing is connected to the input then why do you care what the input is? If you care then consider adding a pull up resistor and/or connect something up.

Comment: Yep, thats it. You have a Pin in an undefined state. This is called floating-pin. As KIIV and blt stated, you should consider a Pull-Up or Pull-Down resistor. Depending on your Arduino, the AtMega comes with internal resistors as well, that can be configured.

Answer (score 6):

This is the correct behavior.

Since you don't connect the pin the read should be undefined (meaning it's unstable). Check ["floating" state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_impedance) to learn more.

If you want to make it stable, consider using the internal pull-up resister. Change the line

> pinMode(Pin, INPUT);

to

> pinMode(Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);

to make it always HIGH while disconnected. In this case you should consider the internal pull-up resistance when you actually try to connect the pin.

[The official Arduino documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) provides more detailed descriptions on each GPIO states.

Answer (score 0):

As the internal pull ups are weak, sometimes adding

```
pinMode(Pin, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

won't solve the problem so you need to add a 10K or higher value resistance between pin and ground/power to initially make the pin pull up or pull down.